# MVC validation, will it conflict with other JS frameworks?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, validation

If I want to use the validation framework that you can use with ASP.NET MVC, will the JavaScript conflict with other JavaScript frameworks like jQuery or YUI?

Comment: Has your question been answered? have you tried it?

Answer (score 1):

No, it will not. Currently, ASP.NET MVC doesn't have an inherent validation framework. So you are free to use any server/client-side validation framework you wish.

Answer (score 0):

There are many MVC frameworks. There are many JavaScript frameworks that have different functionalities. If you want a meaningful answer, you should choose an MVC and a JavaScript framework and ask concerning those two. Please be as detailed as possible in your questions.

As an example, the validation handling on ActiveRecord (used in Ruby on Rails) only performs validations on the server end. You can always add JavaScript validations on top of that, but the server-side validations are what really matters for data integrity.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure Haacked is talking about the ASP.NET MVC Validation shown here:
[ScottGu's Blog - ASP.NET MVC Preview 5 and Form Posting Scenarios](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/09/02/asp-net-mvc-preview-5-and-form-posting-scenarios.aspx)

If this is the case, then the answer is: Yes you can use JQuery in conjunction with this.
Multiple Comments on the linked page talk about using JQuery for Ajax.